# Correlation name is specified multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join different table which happens to have same table's foreign key in multiple tables. I am getting this error

> Msg 1011, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The correlation name 'Amount' is specified multiple times in a FROM clause.

This is what my query looks like

```
SELECT [Allowance].[FullName] [Allowance]
FROM [AppCNF].[tbl_AllowanceOrBenefitType] [Allowance]
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit] [Amount] ON [Amount].[AllowanceOrBenefitTypeCode] = [Allowance].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_PayGradeEarningsAllocation] [Earning] ON [Earning].[AllowanceOrBenefitCode] = [Allowance].[ID] 
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_PayGrade] [Grade] ON [Earning].[PayGradeCode] = [Grade].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [Info] ON [Info].[PayGradeCode] = [Grade].[ID] 
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit] [Amount] ON [Info].[ID] = [Amount].[EmpCode]
```

Can anyone point me out in the right way here?

Comment: you used `Amount` as an alias for 2 tables (even if it's the same table, you need to give it a different alias)

Comment: When I use different alias it does not give me correct result

Comment: that's because you are not giving the correct join conditions, then. If you need to use the same table twice, it's because you need different join conditions for it

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to display in an answer. Note the arrows:

```
SELECT [Allowance].[FullName] [Allowance]

FROM [AppCNF].[tbl_AllowanceOrBenefitType] [Allowance]

LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit] [Amount] <---- ON [Amount].[AllowanceOrBenefitTypeCode] = [Allowance].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_PayGradeEarningsAllocation] [Earning] ON [Earning].[AllowanceOrBenefitCode] = [Allowance].[ID] 
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_PayGrade] [Grade] ON [Earning].[PayGradeCode] = [Grade].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [Info] ON [Info].[PayGradeCode] = [Grade].[ID] 
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit] [Amount] <----- ON [Info].[ID] = [Amount].[EmpCode]
```

You can't have 2 objects with the same alias, thus you'll need to use differents ones. You could just, for example:

```
SELECT [Allowance].[FullName] [Allowance]
FROM [AppCNF].[tbl_AllowanceOrBenefitType] [Allowance]
     LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit] [BenefitAmount] ON [BenefitAmount].[AllowanceOrBenefitTypeCode] = [Allowance].[ID]
     LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_PayGradeEarningsAllocation] [Earning] ON [Earning].[AllowanceOrBenefitCode] = [Allowance].[ID]
     LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_PayGrade] [Grade] ON [Earning].[PayGradeCode] = [Grade].[ID]
     LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [Info] ON [Info].[PayGradeCode] = [Grade].[ID]
     LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit] [InfoAmount] ON [Info].[ID] = [InfoAmount].[EmpCode];
```

*Edit: personally, I prefer to actually use even smaller aliases. For example, for `tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit` I would use EAB (**E**mployee**A**llowanceOr**B**enefit). This turns your query into:*

```
SELECT ABT.FullName Allowance
FROM AppCNF.tbl_AllowanceOrBenefitType ABT
     LEFT JOIN HRM.tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit EAB ON EAB.AllowanceOrBenefitTypeCode = ABT.ID
     LEFT JOIN HRM.tbl_PayGradeEarningsAllocation PGEA ON PGEA.AllowanceOrBenefitCode = ABT.ID
     LEFT JOIN HRM.tbl_PayGrade PG ON PGEA.PayGradeCode = PG.ID
     LEFT JOIN HRM.tbl_EmployeeInfo EI ON EI.PayGradeCode = PG.ID
     LEFT JOIN HRM.tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit EABei ON EI.ID = EABei.EmpCode;
```

*Which makes it a little less bloated (although not by much with those really large column names).*

Comment: Stop answering, you have a perfect 7777 rep right now!

Comment: @DavidG until someone upvotes one of my, other, answers or i downvote an answer :P

Comment: If someone upvotes an answer, I'll downvote another 5!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to apply *additional conditions* to an existing join, not join to the employee allowance table a second time. Something like this:

```
SELECT [Allowance].[FullName] [Allowance]

FROM [AppCNF].[tbl_AllowanceOrBenefitType] [Allowance]

LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAllowanceOrBenefit] [Amount]
    ON [Amount].[AllowanceOrBenefitTypeCode] = [Allowance].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_PayGradeEarningsAllocation] [Earning]
    ON [Earning].[AllowanceOrBenefitCode] = [Allowance].[ID] 
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_PayGrade] [Grade]
    ON [Earning].[PayGradeCode] = [Grade].[ID]
LEFT JOIN [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [Info]
    ON [Info].[PayGradeCode] = [Grade].[ID] 
    AND [Info].[ID] = [Amount].[EmpCode] --<--This condition applies to the Info join
```

Bear in mind, joins are frequently *not* between tables, but are instead between *the results of a previous join* and a new table<sup>1</sup>. The `ON` clause can access any table alias that went into forming that previous result.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or even be a join between two previous join results, when you consider that join ordering can be specified in many different ways and doesn't necessarily follow the "reading" order of a query.